# Determining if a 1-0 matrix that represents a relation is symmetric.

Tags: python, matrix

I know that in a matrix that represents a relation, the relation is symmetric is the 1-0 matrix that represents it has entries that satisfy a_ij = a_ji for row i and col j in a matrix.

Here is my attempt at a solution:

```
def sym(a):
    assert (len(row) == len(a) for row in a)   
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range (len(a)):
            if all(a[i][j] == a[j][i]):
        return True    
    return False
```

Comment: I think you're confused on what `all` does -- it takes a list/iterable of bools and returns `True` if each of the bools its passed are `True`. You can just do `if a[i][j] == a[j][i]:`

Comment: You have mixed tabs and spaces. That's a recipe for pain. Stick to one or the other; spaces are recommended.

Comment: I suggest using a `numpy` array to represent the matrix, instead of a list of lists.  It will be much more flexible, and testing for something of this nature will execute much more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We iterate over the rows of the matrix and do the comparison, like this

```
def sym(a):
    assert set(len(item) for item in a) == {len(a)}
    return all(a[i][j] == a[j][i] for i in range(len(a)) for j in range (len(a)))

a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
print sym(a)
# True
a = [[1, 0]]
print sym(a)
# AssertionError
a = [[1, 1], [0, 0]]
print sym(a)
# False
```